# How to give a friend function a default argument while separating declaration and definition

Tags: c++

I have a function template that I'm declaring as a friend of my class. The thing is, I want to keep the declaration and definition separate because I don't want to clutter the body of `X`, but I'm running into problems when using the default argument of `T()`:

```
struct X
{
    template <class T>
    friend void f(T t);
};

template <class T>
void f(T t = T()) {}

// error: default arguments cannot be added to a function template that has
// already been declared
// void f(T t = T()) {}
//          ^   ~~~
// main.cpp:9:17: note: previous template declaration is here
//     friend void f(T t);
//                 ^
```

If I switch it around to use default arguments in the declaration instead, then the compiler outputs a message saying I have to *define* the function there, but I don't want to do that.

How do I give a default argument to a friend function template while keeping the definition and declaration separate?

Comment: Can you provide a full example that reproduces your problem? I think we need `main.cpp` to test your code.

Comment: @MarkB I just found out it only gives an error in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/512a879c6f0cd813) but not in [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b12aa12c594b661).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For function templates you may only write the default arguments in the *first* declaration in any given scope; and, indeed, there is another rule that prohibits writing the default arguments in the friend declaration:

> `[C++11: 8.3.6/4]:` For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the same scope. *[..]* If a friend declaration speciﬁes a default argument expression, that declaration shall be a deﬁnition and shall be the only declaration of the function or function template in the translation unit.

However, there's nothing stopping you from adding yet another declaration, this time not a friend declaration, before everything else, and put your default arguments on that.

So, in order:

1. Declaration of function template, with default arguments
2. Class definition with friend declaration
3. Definition of function template

Answer (score 2):

I think if you declare the template function before friending it that would work, but I can't figure out what your main.cpp has to test. Did you try this (EDIT: this seems to work on coliru but I can't test your real-world scenario).

```
template <class T>
void f(T t = T());

struct X
{
    template <class T>
    friend void f(T t);
};

template <class T>
void f(T t) {}
```